# How to display information from one contract to another

Tags: solidity, contract-design

I am trying to feed information in a contract and display it in another,

I have 2  contracts provider and user:

In Provider contract I am feeding information like name and address of a user, and I want to display that information in user contract. I can very easily feed info to provider contract but not sure how to display same information in contract user

Comment: Welcome. Possible to post the contracts with a comment about the information you want to see cross the divide? Probably someone will tweak it for you to make an example.